# 'Are' vs. 'Have been' difference in meaning

Tags: difference

> We **have been** able reach an agreement, until we find a peaceful solution to the boundary issue.
>
> We **are** able to reach an agreement, until we find a peaceful solution to the boundary issue.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: As an aside: While the use of _till_ would be okay conversationally, I would recommend using _until_ in more formal writing.

Comment: @J.R. I disagree. The only thing I would not use in formal writing is 'til. see here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until

Comment: Except that neither "till" nor "until" makes sense in context, as both words indicate that some event will not happen before this other event occurs, but the beginning of the sentence indicates that the first event has already occurred. The writer may have meant "We will NOT be able ... until", or maybe "We were able ... since".

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that both sentences are incorrect. First, it doesn't seem to make any sense unless you **negate** the main clause (*be able to reach an agreement*). And, you also need to **make the tenses in both clauses agree with each other**.

If you want to talk about a "not happen yet" condition, you could say:

> We **will not be able** to reach an agreement, **till** we **find** a peaceful solution to the boundary issue.

If you want to talk about something that has just happened, you could say:

> We **were not able** to reach an agreement, **till** we **found** a peaceful solution to the boundary issue.

Comment: I agree with the overall thrust of your answer, but it's worth noting that the agreement could be an interim agreement. But even in that case, the wording could be greatly improved: _We have reached an [interim] agreement until we find a [long-term] peaceful solution._

Comment: Your second sentence is unacceptable: *have not been able* has  present reference and cannot be qualified by a past terminus. You have to say *We **were** not able to ... until we found ...*

Comment: @StoneyB Using *were not able to* sounds much better. However, I still doubt if such a use of *have not been able to* is prohibited. I copied such a usage from *One-act play: Youth* by Thornton Wilder: *Gulliver: I have suffered, madam, principally from thirst, until I found this spring here...* I wonder if that is an error too.

Comment: @DamkerngT. The *have suffered* is a response to Lady Sibyl's inquiry, "You must have suffered...?" I'd point it differently: "I *have* suffered, madam--principally from thirst, until I found, &c"

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you very much. That cleared my doubt perfectly.